# Exclude folders in Plastic SCM

Tags: asp.net, plasticscm

When using Plastic SCM for source control for an ASP.NET application (webforms), what folders are best to exclude for checking in?

And do you add those folders to the cloaked list or the hidden changes list? What is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

Using these three configuration files, you should be able to configure your desired behavior.

***"ignore.conf"*** --> Keep private files as local (not to add to source control)

***"cloaked.conf"*** --> Avoid downloading files from the server even if there are new revisions.

***"hidden_changes.conf"*** --> Ignore changes in controlled files.

Comment: Thanks! But which ASP.NET folders should be in each configuration file?